# Laravel Lumen - Log channels

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I need to log to two different files for two different cases. Something like this:

`Log::channel('case1')->info('msg1')`,

`Log::channel('case2')->info('msg2')`,

How can I do this in Lumen?

I read about Laravel's way of doing this through *channels* https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels and then calling a channel like this: `Log::channel('custom-channel')->info('msg')`, but how do you get this working with Lumen? I can't seem to find the `config/logging.php` file (I only see it in the laravel/lumen-framework repo outside of src, but it's not in laravel/lumen)

Please supply some code examples if you have any idea how to achieve this.
Thanks :)

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/736. If you copy the `laravel/lumen-framework` version into your app's `config/logging.php`, it'll override the defaults.

Comment: Thanks, I still have some issues, but will try to follow the trail in that issue. ..actually I found it easier to just use Monolog directly and wrap it into my own Log class. It's kind of silly that this should be easier to understand than use Lumen, but what to do. The basic example here is what I to twice to get the result I want https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in this case:

```
$log1 = app('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->channel('case1');
$log2 = app('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->channel('case2');

...

$log1->info('msg1');
...
$log2->info('msg2');
...
```

And of course you have to create a config/logging.php like there is in Laravel. There you define the 'case1' and 'case2' channels. This gets picked up by the framework automatically.